# JavaScript slice() explode on base of space(" ")

Tags: javascript, input, slice

I want to get a last word from input field. 
If some write **where** it get **where** if some one put **where are** then it get **are**
and if some one put **where are you going** then it give **going**.
I am using this code but this is not working. Please guide me.
Here is a code.

```
<body>
<input type="text" id="test" onkeyup="checkit()" />
<div id="content">

</div>
</body>
```

Here is javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkit(){
    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    var data = document.getElementById("test").value;
    var cdata = data.slice(" ");

        content.innerHTML = cdata;

}
</script>
```

Thanks........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkit(){
    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    var data = document.getElementById("test").value;
    var cdata = data.split(" ");

        content.innerHTML = cdata[cdata.length-1];

}
</script>
```

Comment: If the last char is a space the last array element will be an empty string

Comment: Yeah but in a correct sentence there shouldn't be any trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

use this....

```
function checkit(){

    var content = document.getElementById("content");

    var data = document.getElementById("test").value;

    var cdata = data.split(" ");

    content.innerHTML = cdata[cdata.length-1];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
function checkit(){

var content = document.getElementById("content");
var data = document.getElementById("test").value;
var cdata = data.split(" ");
//alert(cdata.length);

    content.innerHTML = cdata[cdata.length-1];

}
```

[Here's Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gMaxF/)

Answer (score 0):

You need the last element in the array after the split.

`content.innerHTML = cdata[cdata.length-1];` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

To split with spaces and trim and avoid multiple spaces giving empty strings in the result you can split using a RegExp : `data.match(/[^\s]+/g)`